# Rails 2.3.2 trying to render ERB instead of HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Rails is suddenly trying to render ERB instead of Haml and I can't figure out why. I've created new rails projects, reinstalled Haml, and reinstalled Rails.

Here's exactly the steps I take when making my application (Rails 2.3.2):

```
  rails> rails test
  rails> cd test
  rails\test> haml --rails .
  rails\test> ruby script\generate model user email:string password:string
  rails\test> ruby script\generate controller users index
  rails\test> rake db:migrate
```

Here's what the UsersController looks like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

My routes:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :users
end
```

I now create *views\users\index.html.haml*:

```
%table
  %th(style="text-align: left;")
    %h1 Users
  - for user in @users
    %tr
      %td= user.email
      %td= user.password
```

Annnd run the server...
I navigate to *localhost:3000\users* and I get this error message:

```
Template is missing

Missing template users/index.erb in view path app/views
```

For some reason Rails is trying to find and render .erb files instead of .haml files.
*vendor\plugins\haml\init.rb* exists, untouched.

I've reinstalled Haml (Pretty Penny) multiple times and still get the same results.
I've also tried adding config.gem 'haml' to my environment.rb but this also doesn't work.

I can't figure out why suddenly rails will not render haml for me.

Comment: I've reinstalled Rails again and now I don't have the problem anymore. No idea where it was commin' from.

Answer (score 7):

Hi it seem like haml is  not enabled as Rails plugin  ,in order to enable it use the following command .

Go to your application folder from the command prompt type the following

```
  $ cd ..
  $ haml --rails <yourproject>
```

if this doesnot work try installing  haml  gem   with the following code

```
$ gem install haml
```

I tried with above example , it did work for me  ,i have haml gem installed in my ubuntu system .

Good luck !

NOTE: "haml --rails" was deprecated in HAML 3.1

Comment: As stated above, I already tried this. I'm not having problems anymore, though. I had to reinstall rails twice to get it to work.

Thank you, though =)

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that the fact that the error message says that it couldn't find index.erb doesn't mean that it didn't look for index.haml too. The erb extension is hard-coded into the error message.

I thought that I had the same problem you describe, but it turned out that my application simply couldn't find my partial at all - it had nothing to do with the file extension.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423935/actionviewmissingtemplate-with-haml)) with Rails 2.3.4. Multiple gem uninstall/gem install rails didn't fix the problem. But downgrading to Rails 2.3.2 worked! (I know HAML previously worked in this project with this version of Rails).

```
sudo gem install -v 2.3.2 rails
```

Comment: I've confirmed that I don't have HAML problems when I specify Rails 2.3.2 in my environment.rb, but do have problems with 2.3.4 (I installed both versions so I could switch between them).

Comment: Fixed my problem. It was a html.haml vs. haml.html file extension issue. See the post referenced in this answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Using Rails 3.1, I ran in to the same error and had to restart the web server.

Answer (score 1):

I have this old project in rails 2.3.18, where the gems are managed using bundler, and all I had to do was explicitly use version 3.1.3 It did not work with the latest version (4.0). So in my version I added

```
gem 'haml', '3.1.3'
```

did bundle install and restarted my development server :)

Comment: If you use `gem 'haml', '~> 3.0'`, that should allow it to choose the latest 3.x version.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm strange, this might be related.

According to: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/101346 you should use **resource_url** helpers in controllers and **resource_path** helpers in views. Right?

BUT, if I do use a **resource_url** helper in a **redirect_to** call inside my *controller*, then I get:

*Missing template htp://localhost:4000/categories/new.erb in view path app/views*

If I use the **resource_path** helper instead, there aren't any problems at all.
Anyone knows what could be wrong?

Why is the **resource_url** helper trying to redirect to an .erb file?

This is the error from the server log:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template http://localhost:4000/categories/new.erb in view path app/views):
haml (2.2.2) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:13:in `render'
app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:15:in `create'
haml (2.2.2) rails/./lib/sass/plugin/rails.rb:19:in `process'
```

P.S. This is in **Rails 2.3.3**

Answer (score 0):

maybe your file name is wrong, if you have a whitespace in the end of the index.html.haml_, rails will wrong...

Comment: Nope, I changed nothing in the Rails application directory.. I just reinstalled Rails and it worked *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

Updated - Not actual anymore:

I name all of my haml file only .haml

To illustrate:

```
test.haml
# not
test.html.haml
```

Update 5 years later:

I recommend to name them "file.format.haml", because its much more clear which format is the outcome...

Comment: It never mattered for me.. Rails always rendered .html.haml and .haml files

Comment: Yes, actually this is not good at all. This will work in most cases, unless you want to make a difference based on asked content-type, e.g. `test.js.haml` (xhr call) and `test.html.haml`. It is better to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I had to restart my server after installing Haml before my rails app recognized the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with Ruby 1.9x, Rails 2.3.5, and HAML 3.1.  I believe part of the issue is that some of the deprecated calls in 1.8 were removed in 1.9.

IMHO, if you want to use HAML in Rails 2, you'd be better off downgrading to Ruby 1.8.  (which is what I did to fix my problem).  In Rails 2, you MUST have the gem.config "haml" in your config.

Even better, move forward to Rails 3 on Ruby 1.9!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem.

The solution is documented in https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/672

You need to add

```
config.after_initialize do 
  require 'haml'
  Haml.init_rails(binding)
end
```

inside your config/environment.rb within the `Rails::Initializer.run do |config|` configuration block !!

Comment: I did not need to do this, I just needed to explicitly use version 3.1.3