# ActionView::MissingTemplate with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm getting Ruby on Rails set up on a fresh installation of Snow Leopard. After battling (and [beating](http://sl.maxmasnick.com/post/187931754/getting-rails-sphinx-mysql-working-on-snow-leopard)) MySQL and Sphinx problems, I'm stuck on a stupid error related to HAML.

Essentially I'm getting a missing template error for every view that uses HAML. I can add a blank xxx.html.erb file and and a (blank) page loads fine. But xxx.html.haml throws the error, even though that file definitely exists in the appropriate directory.

Here is the error from the development server:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template sections/index.erb in view path app/views):
  haml (2.2.4) rails/./lib/sass/plugin/rails.rb:19:in `process'
```

I am using the haml gem (2.2.4), rails gem (2.3.4), and ruby 1.8.7. I did run haml --rails . from my RoR app root directory; the init file is in the vendor/plugins/haml directory. I have confirmed that "require 'haml'" => true via IRB.

Any help would be appreciated!

**In response to Yaraher:**

Tried un- and re-installing, which raised no errors except with the rdocs ("Could not find main page README.rdoc").

In script/console:

```
>> require 'haml'
=> []
```

**Update:**

Installing an old version of Rails known to work with HAML in this project seems to have "fixed" the problem. I'd still be curious to hear a real answer to this problem -- I don't want to be stuck at 2.3.2.

```
sudo gem install -v 2.3.2 rails
```

**Update 2:**

This is definitely caused by a difference between Rails 2.3.2 and 2.3.4. With both gems installed I can set which is used in my environment.rb file. HAML works fine with 2.3.2 and breaks as described with 2.3.4.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it? Have you tried requiring it through the script/console?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150339/rails-2-3-2-trying-to-render-erb-instead-of-haml

Comment: I can't reproduce this... I tried creating a bare Rails 2.3.4 app with a single controller and a single Haml view, and it worked fine. Would you mind creating a tarball of the app where it's failing and sending it to me at nex342@gmail.com? This sounds like a Haml bug that I'd like to squash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time for the embarrassing answer to this question:

There is a difference between Rails 2.3.2 and 2.3.4 that does not recognize `xxx.haml.html` files as files that should be parsed by HAML (or ERB); this worked fine in 2.3.2. HAML files should always be named `xxx.html.haml` anwyay, so this isn't even a bug.

I didn't realize that this was the problem because I had the "hide file extensions" option turned on (on by default) in my fresh Snow Leopard installation. So when I tried switching the file extension through Finder to `html.haml` to test this, it actually changed it to `haml.html.haml` or some nonsense.

Moral of the story: I ran the following script and now HAML works with Rails 2.3.4.

```
path = '/path_to_rails_app/views/'
dir = Dir.new(path)
dir.each do |d|
  if File.directory?(path+d)
    Dir.new(path+d).each do |f|
      if (f =~ /.*\.haml\.html$/) != nil
        File.rename(path+d+'/'+f, path+d+'/'+f.gsub('haml.html', 'html.haml'))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your template to

```
sections/_index.haml
```

or

```
sections/__index.haml
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Wouldn't this just tag the templates as partials?